# How to perform penance to Lord Indra?

Tags: indra, tapasya

If one is interested to perform penance for Lord Indra, what is the procedure to follow?
How long does it take for this to succeed? Does the person get boons? Are there any books available?
Usually, they say it is impossible to do penance without a guru, where can we find them?
What is the mantra to do this?

To which Hindu god/goddess do people perform penance to get boons and in a short period of time?

Answer (score 1):

One can perform penance to Lord Indra by doing a Samvatsara Vrata. The presiding deity of this vrata is Indra.

There is interesting story described in Adi Parva-Sambhava Parva - Chapter 122- Of    [**Mahabharata**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01124.htm) , where there is story of birth of Yudhisthira ,Bhima and Arjuna. Pandu father of all the pandavas performed the penance to Indra by keeping this vrata for one year.

---

This story is associated with birth of Arjuna ,Pandu performed Samvatsara Vrata of indra as he wanted a very superior son who shall achieve worldwide fame. Rishis adviced Pandu to perform penance to Indra to obtain a boon for a very powerful son who will defeat humans , daityas and danavas etc. in battle.

> तत: पाण्डुर्महाराजो मन्त्रयित्वा महर्षिभि : |
>  दिदेश कुन्त्या
>   कौरव्यो **व्रतं सांवत्सरं** शुभम् ||25 ||
>  आत्मना च
>   महाबाहुरेकपादस्थितोSभवत |
>  उग्रं स **तप** आस्थाय परमेण समाधिना
>   ||26||
>  आरिराधयिषुर्देवं त्रिदशानां तमीश्वरम |
>  सूर्येण सह
>   धर्मात्मा पर्यतप्यत भारत ||27 ||
>  तं तु कालेन महता वासव:
>   प्रत्यपद्यत ||
>
> P.257 - After this, the Kuru king Pandu, taking counsel with the great
>   Rishis commanded Kunti to observe an auspicious vow for one full year,
>   while he himself commenced, O Bharata, to stand upon one leg from
>   morning to evening, and practise other severe austerities with mind
>   rapt in meditation, for gratifying the lord of the celestials.

The brief procedure of penance by  doing Samvatsara vrata of Indra is also describe in the chapter. Its said that pandu performed penance of Indra  by Mind , speech and deeds. He meditated upon  Indra in fullest of his concentration and standing on one leg from sunrise to sunset for one year. And then Indra then granted him the boon of powerful son as he desired by satisfying with  his penance .

So basically the penance of Indra can be performed by one of the method called  Samvatsara Vrata . And as describe in Mahabhhrrata one can get boons from Indra by performing tapas by this way . This penance has to be performed for full one year in which one has to meditate on Indra with full devotion and concentration along with control of mind , speech and deeds.

---

We  here can read this story of Pandu's penance of Indra in [**Hindi.**](http://%09https://archive.org/details/Mahabharata04SanskritHindiPanditRamnarayanGitaPress/page/n413)